# Unable to access data from Express API from React Axios call, but able to get data through browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, express, axios

I have an Express backend for an API and I'm trying to get data to my React front end. I am able to navigate to the address in my browser and get the data without a problem. Then I'm using axios in React to access the API data shown in the browser screenshot. I've included my React code along with my browser data and response header from the browser access.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class TestQuery extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            pitches: []
         }
    }

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('192.168.0.169:3000/test')
        .then( res => {
            console.log(res);
        })
}
render() { 
    return ( 
        <div>
            test
        </div>
     );
}
}

export default TestQuery;
```

[React Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLBwj.png) [Data in Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5Qux.png) [Response Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLALO.png)

Comment: Please do not put snippets of code into images, but copy it from your editor and add it to the code so we can test it.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Does your api have cors? Try to test your route using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/) or [insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/download/).

Comment: I used the RESTED add on for Firefox and get a 200 response and all the data shows there. And I do have CORS enabled on express.

Comment: Add `http:// ` before ip and test. Ex `http://192.168.0.169:3000/test`

Comment: I can't believe that was it. Thank you so much!